# Is it possible to build a binary package with poky?

Tags: package, packaging, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

As given in [mega-manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html),

> **4.2.2.2**. **Creating the Project**
>
> You can create two types of projects: **Autotools-based**, or
> **Makefile-based**. This section describes how to create Autotools-based
> projects from within the Eclipse IDE. For information on creating
> Makefile-based projects in a terminal window, see the section "Using
> the Command Line" in the Yocto Project Application Developer's Guide.

I want to deploy a separate binary package, I don't want to create an image including my package. Isn't it possible to build a binary package like `.ipk` `.deb` `.rpm` using `poky`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, packages are always created. Autotools and Makefiles are for configuring/building software, so not really related to the question.

Use the [PACKAGE_CLASSES](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PACKAGE_CLASSES) variable in your configuration to select the package types you want to build with Yocto/OpenEmbedded. When you "bitbake recipe-name" the packages are built in the deploy directories under [recipe WORKDIR](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-WORKDIR).

Please don't expect the packages to be compatible with some other operating system though: they will be tailored for your specific configuration. If you already have an image running exactly that configuration, then it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @jku, I also found [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774826/Adding-rd-party-components-to-Yocto-OpenEmbedded-L) which is very helpful.